# How to run GET request in for loop with vueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to populate make GET REST calls from a vuejs app.

Currently I have the following template

```
<template>
<div class="app-container">
  <div class="currentjob">
    <h1>Current Jobs</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>AlgorithmID</th>
        <th>Result</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="job in jobs">
        <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ job.algorithmId }}</td>
        <td>{{ getResult(job.id) }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default
    {
        name: 'CurrentJobs',
        data()
        {
            return {
                jobs: null
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
            this.$axios
                .get(this.$baseUrl + 'job')
                .then(response => (this.jobs = response.data))
        },
        methods:
        {
            getResult: function(jobid)
            {
                  this.$axios.get(this.$baseUrl + 'job/result/'+jobid).
                    then(response =>
                      {
                       return response.data // does not work 
                      }) 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Usually I can run a GET request the following way

```
this.$axios.
  get(this.$baseUrl + 'job/result/'+jobid).
  then(response =>
    {
     // return response.data // does not work 
    }
  )
```

But I can not add a return statement in the arrow function inside the `then` method. How can I return the the response of the REST call? What underlying concept am I missing?

Comment: why you not calling your request in getResult method ?

Comment: I tried adding the code to the method but it does not get returned

Comment: First, you should ideally return the detail data in the original call. If that isn't possibly, then you would be better served initiating your calls to get the details in the success handler that gets the jobs. You won't be able to do this in the template.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.$axios.
get(this.$baseUrl + 'job/result/'+jobid).
then(response =>
{
 this.jobs = response.data 
}
)
```

by doing this, you are passing the response to your `jobs` data

Comment: I do not want to replace the `jobs` object. Each job request its own results via id

Comment: create another `data` variable and store it there, then you can use that variable.

Comment: But then having only one variable the results would be the same for each call since each call have another result. this would defeat the purpose

Answer (score 0):

**Return your `axios` result when you calling this.**

**Example:**

```
getResult: function(jobid)
     {
       return this.$axios.get(this.$baseUrl + 'job/result/'+jobid).
        then(response =>
        {
            return response.data
        })
     }
```

Comment: I added your code. In the `console.log` the object is correct but the website displays an empty objects

Comment: since I return the object the Vue dev tool shows that the return value is empty

Comment: try to recheck the response of your request. debug with console log inside "then" callback in axios.

Comment: Yes I did that the console log is in the correct then method.  when I use `return ""+this.$axios.get(this.$baseUrl + 'job/result/'+jobid).then(response =>       {        return response.data        })`  i get promise  object